# Show Ubuntu Unity's Laucher through command line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, sh, ubuntu-unity

**How can I show Ubuntu Unity's Launcher panel through terminal?**

I'm trying to bind a mouse button to this, showing the launcher. By "launcher" I mean the vertical panel with the "Home button". I would like to press this particular mouse button and it acts as if I had pressed the `<Super>` key; which is bound to show the launcher by default.

I've set `xbindkeys` properly already. I know I could use `xdotool` (or `xte`) to simulate a `<Super>` keypress event, but I'm not willing to do that. I would rather use a more direct solution. Couldn't find any Unity's interface to do that though. Does anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be considered [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You may want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the window manager code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the trick with:

```
xdotool key alt+F1
```